# Generate separate eclipse projects using CMake

Tags: c++, eclipse, build, cmake, eclipse-cdt

I'm using CMake to generate a Eclipse CDT project. This "project" really contains a ton of sub-projects in our repo. This is because I'm defining

```
project (sample_project)
```

in my `CMakeLists.txt` files and using

```
add_subdirectory(sample_project_directory)
```

in my parent directory to chain all my `CMakeLists.txt` together. When I run `cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" ..\src` it will actually generate just one `.project` and `.cproject` file and uses virtual folders to add all the sub-projects. I would much rather generate a separate project file per project. This way I can build each project individually rather than everything in one go. Is this possible? When I generate it for Visual Studio it will generate a master Solution file with a bunch of Projects for every `project (sample_project)` I've defined. This is much more ideal.

Comment: I found this > https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake-developers/2011-April/013275.html but it looks like that development effort is dead. It also would be nice if CMake just supported this and I didn't have to make my own custom generator.

Comment: More good info > https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/15298 Looks like people want this but it doesn't exist

Comment: More people wanting this > https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15298

Comment: More > https://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2011-October/046901.html